# Django's post_save signal behaves weirdly with models using multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

Django's post_save signal behaves weirdly with models using multi-table inheritance

I am noticing an odd behavior in the way Django's post_save signal works when using a model that has multi-table inheritance.

I have these two models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Dog(Animal):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I have a post save callback called echo_category:

```
def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
    print "category: '%s'" % kwargs['instance'].category
post_save.connect(echo_category, sender=Dog)
```

I have this fixture:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "animal.animal",
        "fields": {
            "category": "omnivore"
        }
    },

    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "animal.dog",
        "fields": {
            "color": "brown"
        }
    }
]
```

In every part of the program except for in the post_save callback the following is true:

```
from animal.models import Dog
Dog.objects.get(pk=1).category == u'omnivore' # True
```

When I run syncdb and the fixture is installed, the echo_category function is run.  The output from syncdb is:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --noinput
Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '~/my_proj/animal/fixtures'.
category: ''
Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

The weird thing here is that the dog object's category attribute is an empty string.  Why is it not 'omnivore' like it is everywhere else?

As a temporary (hopefully) workaround I reload the object from the database in the post_save callback:

```
def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    instance = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    print "category: '%s'" % instance.category
post_save.connect(echo_category, sender=Dog)
```

This works but it is not something I like because I must remember to do it when the model inherits from another model and it must hit the database again.  The other weird thing is that I must do instance.pk to get the primary key.  The normal 'id' attribute does not work (I cannot use instance.id).  I do not know why this is.  Maybe this is related to the reason why the category attribute is not doing the right thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because data loaded from fixture with `loaddata`/`syncdb` command is saved as *raw* in the database: only the fields of the resulting model table get saved, to avoid hitting the database for all the models in the class hierarchy.

But, when a model is saved *as raw*, you get an extra `raw` keyword argument in your signal, so you can handle the case properly. Your signal would end up like that:

```
def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('raw', False):
        instance = sender.objects.get(pk=kwargs['instance'].pk)
    else:
        instance = kwargs['instance']
    print "category: '%s'" % instance.category

post_save.connect(echo_category, sender=Dog)
```

This way, you will only get the extra database query when dealing with fixtures (and I guess that's acceptable in your case).

About your other question:

> The other weird thing is that I must do instance.pk to get the primary key. The normal 'id' attribute does not work (I cannot use instance.id). I do not know why this is.

`id` and [`pk`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.pk) have a slightly different semantic. In your example, the `id` of a `Dog` object is the `AutoField` defined ([automagically](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id1)) in your `Animal` class. The `pk` however, is an `OneToOneField` (once again, [automagically defined](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id7)) in the `Dog` class.

In practice, both field have the **same** value all the time. However, as `id` is a field coming from `Animal`, it won't exists for `Dog` object saved as *raw*.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: this issue has already been reported on django's trac [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13299).