# Django post_save signal on parent class with multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, multi-table-inheritance

In Django, if you have models that use multi-table inheritance, and you define a receiver for a post_save signal on the parent class, does that receiver function get called when an instance of the child class is saved?

Borrowing an example [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604800):

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Dog(Animal):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
    print "category: '%s'" % kwargs['instance'].category

post_save.connect(echo_category, sender=Animal)
```

If I do:

```
>>> dog = Dog.objects.get(...)
>>> dog.category = "canine"
>>> dog.save()
```

Will the `echo_category` receiver function be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:
 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318
It appears that most propagate the signal to the super in the subclass.

Answer (score 16):

```
post_save.connect(my_handler, ParentClass)
# connect all subclasses of base content item too
for subclass in ParentClass.__subclasses__():
    post_save.connect(my_handler, subclass)
```

have a nice day!

Comment: Where can you put that snippet safely so all subclasses are already registered?

Comment: @ScottStafford In the [app ready method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

Comment: That doesn't work. Subclasses are empty in app ready method.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be called. See [#9318](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318) in Django trac.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get inherited signal receivers working with the `@receiver` decorator. [See relevant Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders)

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Animal(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @receiver(post_save)
    def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
        print ("category: '%s'" % kwargs['instance'].category)

class Dog(Animal):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This solution is valid in **Python 3.6.8 Django 2.2**

When I do this

```
>>> from myapp.models import Dog
>>> dog = Dog()
>>> dog.category = "canine"
>>> dog.save()
category: 'canine'
>>>
```

No problems. Everything seems to work from the shell.

---

Slightly unrelated, but when I edited models through the admin panel There was an issue with it getting called twice so I filtered them by checking the `'created'` kwarg. In one call it was false, the other it was true so I just put in a simple if block. 
Credit for that workaround goes to [Pratik Mandrekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514919/pratik-mandrekar) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013253/4637870):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Animal(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @receiver(post_save)
    def echo_category(sender, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.get('created'):
            print ("category: '%s'" % kwargs['instance'].category)

class Dog(Animal):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: I have tried this but the receiver seems to get called whenever ANY model gets created for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which worked better for me than the `__subclasses__()` method due to multiple layers of model inheritance  was to use `get_models()`.

Put this in `signals.py` which is imported in the `ready()` method of the `AppConfig` as [recommended by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

```py
from django.apps import apps
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from .models import Parent


def listener(sender, **kwargs):
    ...


for model in apps.get_models():
    if not issubclass(model, Parent):
        continue

    # This catches subclasses and the Parent model itself since from 
    # the python docs "a class is considered a subclass of itself" and
    # only considers concrete models.
    post_save.connect(listener, sender=model)
```